# cache with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I allready have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // one time stuff
    $.ajaxSetup({
      cache:false
    });
}
```

And i now it works cause i had a problem without it and i added it for a file that i read every 100ms. Only that was for this:

```
$.getJSON('output.json', function(data){    
    faceDetected = data.faceDetected;
    frameCount = data.frameCount;   
});
```

It doesn't work for this:

```
function loadContent(page){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {

            $("#content").html(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", page, true);
    xmlhttp.send()

}
```

Does someone know how to fix?

Comment: And the `<p>` tag is present?

Comment: Note, your `id` tags don't follow spec. [HTML 5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-id-attribute), [HTML 4](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/attrs.html).

Comment: And at least a straight test, seems to work (no AJAX): http://jsfiddle.net/aTtwX/

Comment: damnit it's my cache, let me edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is jQuery and the `cache: false` setting is only about jQuery.

The second is using the native `XMLHttpRequest` object. To bust the cache in the second example you could append a timestamp and a random number to the query string.

```
var noCache = new Date().getTime() + Math.random() * 1234567;
xmlhttp.open("GET", page + '&noCache=' + stamp, true);
```

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2006/12/stupid-ajax-cache-problem-solution.html) for a more elaborate solution.